# reloading image in wpf window after changing the image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, data-binding

Recently I was working with WPF and C#, and I wanted to make an editor for an A4 page (A JPG template with the size of an A4)

The thing is, I want to put some text in a certain place on the JPG and to be able to see it as I write the text (like a live preview).

This is what I achieved by now:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Tut.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tut"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Neshalet Logo ltd." Height="900" Width="1400">
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Grid Height="839">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Margin="0,2,22,817" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="15">
                בחר מוצר
            </TextBlock>

            <!-- Combo box for product type -->
            <ComboBox x:Name="productType" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Margin="10,0,17,0"  >
                <ComboBoxItem>באנרים</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>שקפים וניירות</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>וינילים</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>קשיחים הדפסה ישירה</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>הדבקה</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

            <Image Source ="/Resources/a4.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,35,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            </Image>

                <!-- Main window -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,40,0,0">
                <Grid  Height="492">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- SO Number-->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,22,472"><Run Text="מספר הזמנה"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox x:Name="SO" DataContextChanged="drawSO" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>

                    <!-- Costumer name -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,34,22,440"><Run Text="שם לקוח"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,5,0"/>

                    <!-- Order date -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,64,22,410"><Run Text="תאריך"/></TextBlock>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="9,62,122,410" Click="getDate" Content="היום" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                    <DatePicker x:Name="todaysDate" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,60,5,0"/>

                    <!-- Supply date -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,93,22,381"><Run Text="תאריך אספקה"/></TextBlock>
                    <DatePicker x:Name ="deliveryDate" Margin="0,90,5,377"  />

                    <!-- Folder -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,123,22,351"><Run Text="נשמר בתיקיה"/></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="folderName" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,120,5,347">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="ktanot"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="GZM"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="UV"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="SLAVA WATER PRINTS"/>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <!-- Folder -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,154,22,320"><Run Text="קוד משלוח"/></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="DeliveryCode" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,150,5,317">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="איסוף עצמי"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="מסירה"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="משלוח"/>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <Button Margin="230,362,270,96" Click="Button_Click">
                        כאן
                    </Button>

                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Content="תצוגה מקדימה" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>

        </Grid>

        <!-- Image preview -->

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

C#

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today.Date;

    String path = @"/Resources/a4.jpg";

    Bitmap order = null;

    Font f = new Font("Arial", 200, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    private void getDate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String t = today.ToShortDateString();
        todaysDate.Text = t;
    }


    private void drawSO(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String orderNum = SO.Text;
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            order = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
        }
        using (order)
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(order))
        using (f)
        {
            graphics.DrawString(orderNum, f, System.Drawing.Brushes.White, order.Height/2, order.Width/2);
            order.Save(path);
        }

    }
}
```

The thing is that I made the program write the text only on a button click (as you can see on `Button_Click()`, but I want to to display the text I write on **SO Number** text box while I'm writing it.
Is there any way to refresh the image view on the window as I write the text and **not** on a Button click event?

Here is an example:
I want the text entered in the text box will be on the jpg

[image: I want the text entered in the text box will be on the jpg]

Comment: If you would have used Binding then you could Bind the `Text` value of the `TextBlock` to the `Text` property of `TextBox`. Problem solved, make sure you set the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to use the `TextBox`'s `Text`.
Like so:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,22,472" Text="{Binding ElementName=SO, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

> After the comments and the edited question.

You could place the `TextBlock` after the `Image` in a grid and then generate new image with all of the visuals included.
It would go something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="imageToExport">
    <Image Source ="/Resources/a4.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,35,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Some text here that will appear on top of the image"/><!-- The text property can use binding instead -->
</Grid>
```

Then you would save it as a jpeg, like this:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
FormattedText text = new FormattedText("ABC",
    new CultureInfo("en-us"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(this.FontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new 
FontStretch()),
    this.FontSize,
    this.Foreground);

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(2, 2));
drawingContext.Close();

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(180, 180, 120, 96, 
PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);//In here you could just pass the name of the grid "imageToExport"
myImage.Source = bmp;
```

**NOTE**
Please note the code for saving the visual is from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-bitmap-from-a-visual)

Comment: I think I was misunderstood.. the solution you gave changed the textBlock , I want to paste a text on the image , the same text inside the TextBox .
Edited my question , please give it a look :)

Comment: Updated my answer, I think this is what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is that I made the program write the text only on a button click (as you can see on `Button_Click()`, but I want to to display the text I write on SO Number text box while I'm writing it. Is there any way to refresh the image view on the window as I write the text and not on a `Button` click event?

Try to handle the `TextChanged` event for the `TextBox` instead of handling the `Click` event for the `Button`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SO" TextChanged="" ... />
```

---

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    String orderNum = SO.Text;
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        order = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
    }
    using (order)
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(order))
    using (f)
    {
        graphics.DrawString(orderNum, f, System.Drawing.Brushes.White, order.Height / 2, order.Width / 2);
        order.Save(path);
    }
}
```

Note that the event handler will be invoked on each key press. If this is not desired for performance reasons, you might consider binding to a `string` property and implement some delay as suggested [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/12/02/wpf-45-adding-a-delay-to-your-binding-updates-to-reduce-noise).

Comment: This is the comment i've been looking for! you got my mind mate!
but there are 2 problems:
1. it gives me an exception when typing more than 1 character
2. the link you posted is broken :(

Comment: @t0nty: Link fixed. What kind of exceptions are you getting and where?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'  On line  graphics.DrawString(orderNum, f, System.Drawing.Brushes.White, order.Height / 2, order.Width / 2);

Comment: Well, it's the same code as before. You need to debug and find out what the difference is between a working invocation and a failing one.

Comment: got it, it gets the first letter as the whole string and than if I'm adding one more character the program is crashing, the delay should work?

Comment: What's the difference between thr first and second execution? Once you have figured this out, you should be able to solve the issue. There is no delay when the events are being raised.

Comment: the first executed when I press on a button , the second executed when I type a letter.
Don't get it :(

Comment: Any solution maybe?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. As I have mentioned, the TextBox_TextChanged event handler is invoked each time you enter a character into the TextBox.

Comment: yeah and i want it to do the same effect it did on `XAMIMAX`'s first answer .
for any change in the SO textBox i want to see the same text on the jpg on the left - but "live" ! - like mirroring the text as I type it into a certain point on the Image - IN OTHER WORDS : I want to see the text in "SO" textBox on the red preview on the left as I type the text.
save the image on a button click after I see if the text is ok on the preview